# AngularJS $parse returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call the following method of the resource.

```
if($scope.type === 'User') 
  User.query($scope.query)
else if($scope.type === 'Product') 
  Product.query($scope.query)
else
  Item.query($scope.query)
```

I found some similarities, and I decided to use eval.

It worked like a charm

```
eval($scope.type).query($scope.query).$promise...
```

But jshint warn me that using eval is not cool. I decide to use Angular's $parse method.

```
var method = $parse($scope.type + '.query') //function (s,l,a,i){var v5,v6, ...

method($scope, $scope.query).$promise...
```

Error:

```
Cannot read property '$promise' of undefined
```

My code is located in some directive controller, and I'm sure that

```
eval($scope.type).query($scope.query).$promise
```

works.

EDIT: `method` is some incomprehensible function, but exists. When I call it with context=$scope and arguments it returns undefined.

Comment: Error says that '$parse($scope, $scope.type + '.query')($scope, $scope.query)' is undefined.

Comment: Split each process out so you can see the variables at that point to see where your error lies. First the call to `$parse` then calling the method returned then finally the response from that method. The exception explains it all, you can do this yourself really. Also for reference [reference ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!)

Comment: You haven't posted all the relevant code but unless you have  `$scope.User.query`, it won't work as you expect. $parse and $scope.$eval don't do eval internally.